# what do I do to fix the Value Error: invalid literal error I keep getting

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting a Error called

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'add'
```

for the following code:

```
def calculator():
    print('Input first number')
    n = input()
    
    print('Input second number')
    u = int(input())
    
    print('Input add, minus, multi, divide')
    s = int(input())
    
    add = (n + u)
    minus = (n - u)
    multi = ( n * u)
    divide = (n / u)
    
    if s == add:
        print(add)
        
calculator()
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: What are you inputting to get that result?

Comment: `"add"`is not an `int`, so `int("add")` fails. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You can't convert the string `"add"` to an integer. This code doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look right

```
print('Input add, minus, multi, divide')
s = int(input())
```

I assume you just want a string, not an integer?

```
s = input()
```

Then later do a string comparison

```
if s == 'add':
    print(add)
```

Similarly, your first input is not converted to `int`, so your later arithmetic will have issues.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you have to denote this with int(input ()) since numbers are int

after that, when the action you will get contains characters, it should only be input ()

Since the operand value of your input will contain characters, str is a value so you have to use "add" when equating with if.

```
def calculator():
    print('Input first number')
    n = int(input())

    print('Input second number')
    u = int(input())

    print('Input add, minus, multi, divide')
    s = input()

    add = (n + u)
    minus = (n - u)
    multi = ( n * u)
    divide = (n / u)

    if s == "add":
        print(add)
    
calculator()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do.

````py
def calculator():
    n = int(input('Input first number'))
    #   ^^^
    # First make sure the numbers you are inputting are being changed to integers

    u = int(input('Input second number'))

    # Then this should be kept a string
    s = input('Input add, minus, multi, divide')
    
    add = (n + u)
    minus = (n - u)
    multi = ( n * u)
    divide = (n / u)
    
    # You want to compare the variable s to a string add. Not the variable add
    if s == 'add':
        print(add)
        
calculator()```
````

Answer (score 0):

Here is what will work:

```
def calculator():
    print('Input first number')
    n = int(input())

    print('Input second number')
    u = int(input()) #has to be an integer

    print('Input add, minus, multi, divide')
    s = input() # you can't cast a string of letters to integer

    add = n + u
    minus = n - u
    multi = n * u
    divide = (n / u)

    if s == 'add': #you should be comparing a string to s and not a variable
       print (add)
    
calculator()
```